# When I am adding MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4 System.Web.Mvc version difference error is coming

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I am adding MvcSiteMapProvider in my sample site using Package Manager console like

```
PM> Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4
```

but after installation completion facing below Error.

i.e.

```
uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
```

Error is like below :

```
Error   18  Assembly 'MvcApplication1121097jhgf7621jhg9999, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' c:\Offline\MvcApplication1121097jhgf7621jhg9999\MvcApplication1121097jhgf7621jhg9999\bin\MvcApplication1121097jhgf7621jhg9999.dll   MvcApplication1121097jhgf7621jhg9999.Tests
```

I have changed all references form config files, which are referencing to version 4.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1, but even after that above error is coming. Please help me.

Comment: this issue also comes if you have nuget packages that depends on specific version of Libraries(Mvc in your case).you can also check that if any version depends.Also check csproj file of MvcApplication1121097jhgf7621jhg9999.Tests by open it in editor and look for version of references.